# What type of model should I use? (Time series, univariate, dependent variable is a count)

Tags: time-series, lags, univariate

I have a univariate model in which I am looking to predict the number of articles per week in a newspaper about a protest (count data) by how many arrests of protesters occurred per week. I have 148 weeks in total. My hunch is that I want to lag the independent (or dependent?) variable. Basically I would predict that the arrests of the previous week influence the amount of news coverage for the following week. In simple terms, what kind of model specification would that require? OLS regression?

I've tried the following in R:

```
    > library(dyn)
    > yt <- (OWS$Stories)
    > yt <- ts(OWS$Stories)
    > xt <- ts(OWS$Arrests)
    > dyn$lm(yt ~ xt + lag(yt, -1))
```

The R^2 is great (.82) and both the indy variable as well as the lagged dependent variable are significant are significant in this model. But I worry that this model ignores the count variable nature of the dependent variable. Not sure if this is related, but I also ran a Durbin Watson test and there appears to be significant autocorrelation w/ my dependent variable.

The more complicated part of this is that it's time series count data. I keep reading about poisson and negative binomial models. I guess I can't use these though if I want to capture the time series element? So now I'm reading about poisson autoregression, but I don't know if that's the appropriate model either. I'm thinking I might want to re-specify the model to include a lagged X (arrests from previous week) as well as a lagged Y (stories from previous week). Can anyone point me to the proper specification for a good-fitting model here? Thanks!